# Can gnupg master key decrypt something encrypted with subkey?

Tags: pgp

When creating gpg subkeys, the master key signs and certifies that a subkey belongs to that master. That's ok, but, can master key decrypt something encrypted by a subkey? I guess no, but I want to be 100% sure. Am I right or I misunderstood?

Comment: that's correct. You can not decrypt anything encrypted using a subkey, with the master key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the master private key cannot decrypt anything encrypted by a subordinate public key. Otherwise, it would mean that the master keypair is the same as the subordinate keypair.